# Setting up an Apache Reverse Proxy to access internal apps with multiple domains on the apache config file and enabling SSL using lets encrypt

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, ssl, reverse-proxy, letsencrypt

Many of the ubuntu server tutorials online only show you how to setup a reverse proxy but not explain how to set it up with SSL lets encrypt and setting it up along with other domains on the server. Is there a good concise tutorial on how to setup the following:

- apache reverse proxy to access internal app
- setup ssl lets encrypt for this app to access it via https

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have apache installed on your ubuntu server, you'll need to install the proxy modules using root:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
sudo a2enmod proxy_balancer
sudo a2enmod lbmethod_byrequests
```

When that is installed, you need to modify your /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf file to add in the new site. Using the example below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName xxxx.yyyy.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:26876/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:26876/

        <Directory /var/www>
        AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =testardor.xcubicle.com
      RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

After that is setup, you'll need to restart you apache using: **systemctl restart apache2**

Now on with the SSL setup using lets encrypt. At first it seemed confusing to setup SSL, but it was quite easy. Following this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04

Its as simple as:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot

sudo apt install python-certbot-apache

sudo certbot --apache
```

Follow prompts and your set. Remember to restart your apache.

NOTE: If you have lets encrypt setup already and adding in new domains, you can just delete the 000-default-le-ssl.conf file and just have certbot regenerate it again. I had issues and needed to do this.